# SWIFT: Prototype Cells not being loaded after performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9, xcode7

I have a ViewController that calls (clicking on a button) another View using this function

```
@IBAction func btnSeeContact(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueSeeContact", sender: self)
    }
```

and my prototype cell is "linked" to a custom View Controller named ContactsTableViewCell that I have created and it implements:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
        
        cell.txtName.text = "test"
        cell.txtPhone.text = "1234567890"
        
        return cell

    }
```

When I run the project, the button calls the table, but there is no Cell on it, and I put a breakpoint on those tableView functions and they are not being reached.

What am I missing here that those functions are never being called?

[image]

Comment: can you maybe show a screenshot of your storyboard to get a better understanding?

Comment: You write that `prototype cell is "linked"`, is it cell identifier in `Storyboard`?

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong class name in the storyboard for the view controller which contains the table view. This is the one to which your segue points. So maybe it does not load your custom view controller at all.

Comment: This TableViewController in the screenshot was created by the Navigation Controller. The only other view controller that I have created was ContactsTableVillCell that retains the labels of the cell. The functions like "numberOfRowsInASection" are implemented at the main View Contorller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding a new answer since my previous answer was up voted, so I don't want to make massive edits that one, and is still a valid way to fix your issue.

The issue is you have your custom classes confused.  In your screen shot you can see that the the Table View Controller is not set to a custom class, it just says `Table View Controller`.  That is the object that needs to get a custom implementation of the UITableViewController class.

Instead you seem to be setting the cell's class to a custom class, and implementing the delegate methods there.  You still need a custom class for the table view cell, but it should be a custom class of `UITableViewCell`.

So your cell class should look something like this:

```
import UIKit
class YourCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel1: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel2: UILabel!
}
```

You will be given an instance of this cell to configure in cellForIndexPath.
So your Table view controller class should be set to a class that looks like below.  The YourTableViewController is were you want to implement all the delegate methods.

Note:  if you are using a UITableViewController dragged out from the storyboard, it will already have the tableView, and delegate / data source stuff already wired up for you.  You will also notice that you are overriding the delegate methods as the UITableViewController class has default implementations of these.  If you are just using a normal view controller, then see my previous answer for more details on how to set that up.

```
import UIKit

class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)     
    if let cell = cell as? YourCustomTableViewCell {
      cell.yourLabel1.text = "some text"
      cell.yourLabel2.text = "some other text"
    }
    return cell
  }   
}
```

Comment: Nice, now it works. I created a new ContactTableViewController and made it as the custom class of my table view. I also wasn't over rinding "numberOfSectionsInTableView".

Comment: Do I really need to creat this new TableViewController? Can't I use just the "main" ViewController to implement the tableView functions?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, you really need to provide a little more context.

Here are a few things that might be going wrong,  providing more context would confirm or deny this guesses.

First you don't show the numberOfSectionsInTableView method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
          return 0
  }
```

I think you would need to provide a value other than 0

Secondly, since I don't see `override` in front of what I am sure you are intending to be UITableViewDelegate methods function calls, that means your view controller is not a UITableViewController. This makes me wonder if you defined this view controller as conforming to the UITableViewDelegate protocol and if you set the table view outlet delegate to self. (or even wired up the UITableView to an outlet)

If you use a plain UIViewController to host a table view you need to do the following:

1. Wire up your UITableView to an outlet in your view controller
2. Declare the view controller as conforming to the UITableViewDeleagate (and maybe UITableViewDataSource) protocol
3. set the table view's outlet delegate (and maybe dataSource) properties to self (the view controller implementing the protocols)
4. Implement the required methods

So something like this:

```
class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("your PrototypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it woks. I created another controller, a TableViewController, and put it as the custom class of my table view. I also wasn't over riding the function "numberOfSectionsInTableView". Do I really need to create this new controller? Can't I use the "main" view controller to over ride the tableView functions?